# Sum of n Natural numbers using for loop

Tags: javascript

The question is to calculate the sum of ten natural numbers but the code isn't working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sum of first 10 Natural numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       var sum = 0, n;
       parseInt (prompt("Enter the number: "));
       for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += i; 
       }
       alert ("Sum of Numbers: " + sum);
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code _is_ working just not how you would like. Try some debugging. What is _n_? What value are you assigning to it? Should the prompt go inside the loop? What variable are you assigning the prompt value to?

Comment: "not working" is not a valid problem description. But for starters: you don't assign any value to `n` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code was not working is because you were not saving the value from prompt in a variable.

```js
var sum = 0, n;
n = parseInt (prompt("Enter the number: "));
for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  sum += i; 
}
alert ("Sum of Numbers: " + sum);
```